# PHP RewriteRule detect if url contain "string" and replace

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This may be a basic question regarding RewriteRule but I just counldn't make it work.

What I want to do is detect urls like:

```
mydomain/myapp/id/some/random/url.html?param=somethingThatIdoUse
mydomain/myapp/id/other/randomabc/perrito.php?param=somethingThatIdoUse
...
```

The part that I need to discart is from the `/id/[all this]?param=somethingIdoUse` and use the param if is possible or send the complete url as param so I can regex to get the param.

And have a rule that detect that `/id/` exist and redirect to something like:

```
mydomain/myapp/other/manageRequest.php?params=somethingThatIdoUse
```

(the params I could get the whole url and strip it as string is no problem)

As well the application have different modules like:

```
mydomain/myapp/moduleOne/index.php 
mydomain/myapp/moduleTwo/index.php
```

This have to keep working the same.

As far I've tried some of them like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET /.*;.* HTTP/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule .* http://localhostdev/app/index.php %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /spt/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^id$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/campaings/response\.php$
RewriteRule ^/something/(.*) /other/manageRequest.php? [L]
```

But nothing seamed to do kind of what I needed.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mydomain/myapp/id/some/random/url.html?param=somethingThatIdoUse

Here is an example using the above URL:

```
RewriteRule ^id/some/random/url.html/?  /myapp/other/manageRequest.php [L,NC]
```

The query will be passed through unchanged to the substitution URL

Comment: I cant make it work with "/myapp/other/manageRequest.php" but if I replace that for index.php (for instance)  it works redirects to index.. but adds the prefix of "id/some/random/index.php" so it doesnt find the match. 

as well I've tried for example with 
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] and whenever I enter /some/a/.. is added to the redirected url

Comment: **ups my mistake it works it does redirect** 
...now the thing is that I do want it to be a little more dynamic seance /id/[is constant] but the rest of the url is not .. I mean as it could be some/random/ could be anything that the user wants.. is not controlled by my end to add the rule. so it would be eliminate whatever the user enter between "/id/" and "param?[this value is dynamic as well could be any value]"

Comment: Thanks you point me in the right direction I end up using: 
"RewriteRule ^.*id.*$ handleRequest.php [NC,L]" this search for *id* and redirects!

Answer (score 1):

well actually end up being really basic it worked with:

```
RewriteRule ^.*id.*$ handleRequest.php [NC,L]
```

I do get the params as they are sent!

Comment: +1 Glad you figured out how to modify the rule to meet your requirements.